# How to search in a Listview on working with Fragment layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-listview

[image]

I am working on a Music player project. I have reached up to this stage(shown in image). I have added search bar in the top of the layout but the main problem is the listview of the songs is in the fragment 1 layout as shown, but the search bar option is in my Mainactivity. How can I connect these two so that when the user click the search icon it starts searching in the song list and show the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement `onQueryTextListener` to your fragment with list.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener